# windows8 - output object data as a table

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a class C1 with members Name and Value. I have an ObservableCollection C1Coll which will have around 10 to 20 items. I need to write this data out in an email as a table when user clicks on the email option. 
Any ideas?

Comment: So you are using C#/XAML and want to send an email? Probably using the Share contract?

Comment: yes, I want to use c#/xaml. and how do I write this data out as a table in the email content?